# SOLR index searching across word boundaries

Tags: solr

I am trying to configure a SOLR index of business names to be able to do business name lookups.  Here is a use case that I'm trying to solve for:

My solr index contains "WHOLE FOODS MARKET".  I have a string that I'm trying to look up that has some relevant information and some not relevant information: "WHOLEFDS TRB 10245".

Any help/pointers would be appreciated -- I'm a SOLR novice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the NGRAM filter within the example schema.xml within the zip distribution of solr.

Further links:

[How to use n-grams approximate matching with Solr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309072/how-to-use-n-grams-approximate-matching-with-solr)
http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory